# Find function & variables in MESSAGE_MAP with ID, C++ MFC

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

I have this MESSAGE_MAP which binds a combobox control-event to a function

```
// other definitons
ON_CBN_SELENDOK(IDC_COMBO_LAYER_GROUP, OnSelendokComboLayerGroup)
// more definitions
```

and another line binding the checkbox control to this variable:

```
//DDX_Control(other stuff)
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_COMBO_LAYER_GROUP, m_cLayerGroup);
//DDX_Control(other stuff)
```

I want to change `m_cLayerGroup` in another place and then call the corresponding function to be able to remove the UI from the equation. They share the same ID so I would like to know if/how it is possible to be able to lookup the function/variable given the ID? This will be used for a lot of different functions and variables with different IDs.

I tried to search MSDN but it didn't yield anything..

Comment: Do you mean you want to programmatically change the selected item, and trigger the function as if the user had selected it? You don't need to do a lookup here; use `m_cLayerGroup.SetCurSel()` and it _should_ trigger the function automatically (if it does not, you can use `PostMessage()` to send that notification message).

Comment: This has [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info) written all over it. What are you *really* trying to do?